# Should the ground prong in an AC power cord carry current?

Tags: ac, laptop

[image]

When I use a test light on my laptop charger's head, it turns on.  That means it is shorted somewhere, right?

I used a 3 prong to 2 prong connector and inside it I connected the prong in the image that I marked to the neutral and the test light now won't turn on.

Why does it have current in the ground prong and what causes it? Is what I did safe?

Comment: Please show a precise schematic of the wiring and the 3-prong to 2-prong connector, as well as what the test light represents. Especially with safety-related questions such as these, being precise is very important.

Comment: Which country is that plug for? As it seems to be missing a fuse...

Comment: On a safety note, be aware that the type G plug in the photo is a cutaway version that’s certainly illegal in the UK and if it isn’t in your jurisdiction then it ought to be.  Unlike proper type G plugs it isn’t fused and the small body reduces the clearance around the pins.  The saving grace is that the live and neutral pins are shielded so it is possible to extract the plug without electrocuting yourself.

Comment: @SolarMike there is a fuse inside the power cord

Comment: @nanofarad well im not a master at this website i tried to make a schematic but i don't know how to show prongs and wires like what i did, can i take a photo of it? and also my real question is does ground prong should have current?

Comment: You can include an image, but it should be clear and show the wiring. The ground prong generally should not carry current, but with the way you're mixing ground and neutral together we don't have the info to give a clear answer.

Comment: Since the mains input of a 3-prong power supply would most likely have filter caps from live and neutral to earth/ground prong, yes, there would be some small amount of current flowing, maybe few hundred microamps tops. But I feel like that is not the answer. And modifying equipment to have the earth/ground being connected to neutral with your own wiring at the plug is dangerous and should not be done, no doubt about that. Any fault in the system could make your laptop case dangerous.

Comment: @Justme i think the current is more than that cause even hdmi ports and usb ports makes the test light turn on and laptop shuts down if im using a usb

Comment: If you are talking about a glim lamp tester, it works with extremely low current as long as voltage is enough. The power supply output could be grounded, or it could float and have common mode voltage referenced to earth/ground so it might light up your tester. Please let us know what kind of tester you have and how are you testing.

Comment: @Justme its a screwdriver tester, yes it lights up with low voltages but now that i connected the ground and neutral together so it won't light up the laptop is fine and my bug question is does the ground prong in laptop charger should light up the test light or its broken and how would i know its broken